# Incorrect arithmetic in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

When I try to add or multiply in a python3, I get an obvious error, although the operation is very simple and can be easily verified.

```
# for example:

a = 0.3 * 3
b = 0.3 + 0.3 + 0.3
c = 0.6 + 0.3

print('a = ',a)
print('b = ', b)
print('c = ',c)
```

I expect the answer to be `0.9`, but it is different.

```
a =  0.8999999999999999
b =  0.8999999999999999
c =  0.8999999999999999
```

Can someone explain why this is happening.
I use:
Python 3.6.8 :: Anaconda custom (64-bit)

Comment: [Floating Point Arithmetic: Issues and Limitations](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the decimal module if you want precise decimals. Floats are imprecise approximations.